# Automatic Binding Redirects

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Running VS 2017, latest update.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection) states that to enable automatic binding redirection you modify the csproj file and add the following under the appropriate `<PropertyGroup>`:

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

Historically my project has had a few binding redirect entries in the app.config. I recently updated all nuget packages for the solutions and in the commit it modified several of the binding redirect entries to match the new version.

I wanted to make sure that everything was good to go for QA so I deleted all entries in the App.Config thinking that they would be regenerated on the next build (as the docs suggest they will).

To my surprise nothing has been added to the app.config on a clean / build.

So my question is, is it safe to assume that by consolidating dependencies in the solutions I no longer need them?

Or is there something wrong and VS should be generating the redirects and its failing.

Comment: What if you also add ` <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>` to csproj file?

Comment: @Evk - Tried that one, still doesnt generate the redirects.  However if I make any changes to nuget packages the redirects do get generated.

Comment: Ah, so that seems to be a reason then

Comment: As Dawid Kowalski points out, automatic binding redirects is NOT changing the source app.config, but adds the required binding redirects to the config file in the build output folder, f.ex. called YourApp.exe.config if your project is built to an exe and the namespace is "YourApp".

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Check this article out:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Nov/29/Updating-Assembly-Redirects-with-NuGet

There is a command to force Nuget re-write all the assembly redirects in solution's config files.

Just try this on Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Get-Project –All | Add-BindingRedirect
```

Comment: Note that this does not cleanup after itself and remove any that are now unused. Removing them all first like OP did and then running this is the only way to get a clean list of redirects.

Comment: This does not work with the PackageReference NuGet format, see https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7432

Answer (score 13):

This is because the source app.config is not modified, only output (the one created in a compilation step and placed in your Debug / Release folder) application configuration file is.

> Starting with Visual Studio 2013, new desktop apps that target the .NET Framework 4.5.1 use automatic binding redirection. This means that if two components reference different versions of the same strong-named assembly, the runtime automatically adds a binding redirection to the newer version of the assembly in the output app configuration (app.config) file. This redirection overrides the assembly unification that might otherwise take place. The source app.config file is not modified.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions#relying-on-automatic-binding-redirection)

Redirects in your source app.config were generated by Nuget itself. You have triggered it by making changes to the packages.

Comment: How is it supposed to work with ASP.NET? web.config is not copied to /bin folder.

Comment: See this doc for info on automatic binding redirects in web apps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection#enable-automatic-binding-redirects-in-web-apps

Answer (score 6):

There's a warning that will auto generate your missing redirects.

1. Clean your project
2. Build your project
3. Go to the Error List filter and activate the warning filter
4. Filter warnings for your main project
5. Look for a warning with a message like this:

   > Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file
6. Follow the message. Click it!

**Update**:
You'll have to activate the warning in the project properties -> Application -> Auto-generate binding redirects

Comment: Clicking the warning only opens this file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" and doesn't even copy the redirects to cliupboard!

Answer (score 3):

I had success generating the redirects with editing my .csproj file and adding one of these:

```xml
<Target Name="ForceGenerationOfBindingRedirects"
          AfterTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences"
          BeforeTargets="GenerateBindingRedirects"
          Condition="'$(AutoGenerateBindingRedirects)' == 'true'">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

or

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 3):

Compiling a dll project with VS2019 in a solution using a package.config, I tried to add the following tags to the csproj inside the PropertyGroup section:

```
<GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
<AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences>true</AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences>
```

It did not make any difference. And I removed the tags. I am now convinced that AutoGenerateBindingRedirects is actually true by default.

The solution that I used was this:

For the error/warnings about explicit bindings conflicting with auto generated bindings or suggestion to "consider remapping" bindings, simply update the config file with the suggested versions in the binding redirect definitions:

For instance if the message is this one:

> The explicit binding redirect on "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" conflicts with an autogenerated binding redirect.\ Consider removing it from the application configuration file or disabling autogenerated binding redirects. The build will replace it with: "< bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />"

You will need to update the existing bindingredirect in your config file accordingly:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

There are cases where the package is already present with the latest version in a project that your project is referencing. In that case removing the package reference and the bindingRedirect in your project means that the latest version will be used through transitive reference and the error/warning will be solved.

After having solved all those issues, the build may give an error about conflicting packages without telling you which one are causing the issue.

> Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved. These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

In Tools>Options>Project and Solutions>Build and Run, you can set the MSBuild Project Output Verbosity to Detailed. Then by pressing Ctrl+S in the Output window you can save the output to a file and search it with a text editor. I found some conflicts listed there looking for the string: "No way to resolve conflict". You can then try to figure out how to handle the conflicts listed. Most likely with more binding redirects.

Finally I ended with a build still complaining about conflicts without any information about what was causing the conflict that I could clearly identify in the detailed build output.

The silver bullet was to open **the config file generated for the dll in the bin folder**, with a name like mydll.config. There, were present all the explicit binding redirects I created plus some that had been **automatically generated**. I copied-pasted them in the project app.config file and the error simply disappeared.

So, to conclude, VS correctly identifies and solves the conflicts b/w packages versions by default, without the need to bother about adding the AutoGenerateBindingRedirects and other tags to the csproj. Then, once it has done so it gives you an error message with no useful information at all just to ruin your day.

Comment: For **Windows desktop apps** binding redirect is active by default, the redirects are added to the output configuration (app.config) file when the app is compiled. It changes only the output {project}.config file, the app.config file is not modified
as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection#disable-automatic-binding-redirects-in-desktop-apps)

Comment: For **web apps**, the binding redirect must be added in the web.config file itself. The Visual Studio will prompt to add binding redirects when needed as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection#enable-automatic-binding-redirects-in-web-apps)

Answer (score 0):

In VS2022, go to Properties -> Application -> and check the `Auto-generate binding redirects` checkbox.

Then compile your app, and look inside a new file named `bin\YourApplicationName.dll.config`. It will have your auto-generated binding redirects. Copy them from here and into your `web.config` and you're home free.